# Recibir el codigo de un archivo Python ubicado en otra carpeta

Tags: python

Yo se importar funciones Python de un archivo que se encuentra en el mismo directorio, es algo simple con "import" + el nombre del archivo sin el .py.

Es decir: si el archivo se llama ejemplo.py
y tengo una funcion

```
def ejem():
   print("Hola")
```

En otro archivo solo coloco:

```
import ejemplo

ejemplo.ejem()
```

Mi pregunta: como hago lo mismo si el archivo se encuentra en otra carpeta?

Yo ya logre hacerlo creando un pip (creo que se conoce como dependencia, es decir, una instalacion de todo mi codigo con setup), pero, es un proceso muy complicado y cuando actualizo el archivo no funciona hasta que vuelvo a crear el PIP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el archivo se haya en una subcarpeta de tu programa por ejemplo con el arbol de directorios:

```
main.py
subcarpeta
    ejemplo.py
```

Puedes importar a ejemplo.py desde main de este modo:

```
import subcarpeta.ejemplo
```

Es como poner el path NO absoluto de tu archivo py, pero en vez de usar barras, usas puntos.

---

Si en cambio tienes a ejemplo.py una o más carpetas antes, tendrás que incluir el path a la lista de paths con el modulo sys.
Si tienes el siguiente arbol de directorios:

```
carpeta1
    ejemplo.py
carpeta2
    main.py
```

Antes de importar tu modulo, escribe el siguiente código:

```
from sys import path
path.append("../carpeta1")
```

`..` significa, una carpeta atras. Por ejemplo si tu programa está en el path `C:/carpeta/subcarpeta`, el path `../..` te llevará a `C:/`.

Luego de hacer esto, importa tu modulo del modo "normal"

```
import ejemplo
```

---

Espero haber interpretado correctamente lo que dices. Si mi respuesta no responde a tu pregunta, ponme al tanto así la borro por favor.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si es lo que buscaba (el path.append). Mi pregunta es: es una buena practicar hacerlo de esa forma? Otra pregunta: si tengo varios archivos externos, debo colocar el path.append arriba de todo?

Comment: De nada c: Sobre tu primera pregunta, no conozco otra forma de lograr importar modulos de más atras. Sobre tu segunda pregunta, el path.append va siempre antes de importar cada modulo. Sys.path es una lista de paths donde Python buscará un modulo.

Comment: Más info de esta variable en este link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sys-path-in-python/

Comment: Es decir, si tienes varios archivos, agrega con path.append todos los directorios donde estan esos archivos. No hace falta que agregues el mismo directorio dos veces o más.